# `Message` icon resource from missed call notification

Tags: android, android-resources

In Android JellyBeans we have a feature that allows user to call back or send a text message to the number that we've missed.

[image: Missed call]

What is the ID of `Message` icon resource ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all platform specific resources in android\sdk\platform\android-{version}\data. There are all resource folders like "drawable-hdpi" with icon and drawable resources. After you find needed icon, you can get it programmatically "android.R.drawable.icon_name"

Comment: I've already did it, however there is no matching icon in `drawable-hdpi` directory.

Comment: Then you have to find sources of the phone application, possible this is application specific resources. No other place for resources in android os.

Answer (score 0):

I have found it on [this link](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html).

The name of the icon is "6_social_chat.png" and it is avaialable in Holo Light and Holo Dark. There are only 3 buckets: mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi.

If you want a beautiful and a complete set, check [this link](http://www.androidicons.com/) (you have to pay $20, but it is an honest price). On this set the icon name is "ic_action_sms". This include also ldpi and xxhdpi (i'm sorry for advertising: i have buy this set and i think is very useful!).